# Proper place for oAuth2 clientId & clientSecret

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm working on my web application which supports the oAuth2 authentication with third-part services. So i have my `clientId` and `clientSecret` keys, which i use to authorize my application.

I'm using Spring security oAuth dependency and configure all that in props. And so here's the problem: as i understand, keeping these information in classpath props in unsafe. From the other side, i'm looking for a solution which allows to get my application up and running from the box without any third-part props/configs (so i don't like the idea to put these props on environment side)

I'm wondering if there are any best practices of keeping `clientId` and `clientSecret` keys?

Comment: use application.properties file, it's the best place

Comment: IMHO I think if you use a java based config it will be better that going with properties file config, Take a look here [oauth2 example - java config](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-javaconfig/blob/master/samples/oauth2-sparklr/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth/examples/sparklr/config/OAuth2ServerConfig.java)

Comment: my concern here is about security. Storing these just in java config or application.properties leads to the case when these keys can be stolen (as they are not secured) and reused by another application pretending it's mine. That's why i'm looking for some best practices here.

Answer (score 1):

At Salesforce we stored sensitive information in properties in encrypted way. For example:

```
sensitive.property=ENC(2sfs25D!==)
```

When an app starts it reads those properties, identifies which ones are encrypted and decrypts them. It is possible to add custom logic to spring default @value readings for example.

Depending on your company security guidelines use appropriate encryption algorithm. For example Scrypt:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lambdaworks/scrypt

```
int SCRYPT_N_PARAM = 65536;
int SCRYPT_R_PARAM = 8; 
SCryptUtil.scrypt(str, SCRYPT_N_PARAM, SCRYPT_R_PARAM, 1);
```